# PHP Associative Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I do have a query to get two users from a MySQL database. I'm using PDO.

This is the returned array, using `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["last_activity"]=>
    string(10) "1367361208"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["username"]=>
    string(4) "WiS3"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["a_last_update"]=>
    string(10) "1365785841"
    ["user_level"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["level_color"]=>
    string(6) "FC0000"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    string(2) "19"
    ["last_activity"]=>
    string(10) "1367359866"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["username"]=>
    string(5) "Admin"
    ["gender"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["a_last_update"]=>
    string(10) "1366690422"
    ["user_level"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["level_color"]=>
    string(6) "008AFF"
  }
}
```

Since the rows Array are Numeric, to get data from, i have to do `$row[0][field]` , `$row[1][field]`

But i want it to be Associative using `user_id`, so i can do `$row[user_id][field]`

**It is possible? How i can do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, no built-in for that. You'll have to use [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and populate the array by yourself:

```
$result = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // note that $row['user_id'] will currently a string
    // if you need integers as indexes then use intval($row['user_id']);
    $result[$row['user_id']] = $row;
}

// dump all records 
var_dump($result);

// dump username of user with uid = 4
var_dump($result['4']['username']);
```

Comment: I did that, but i get double values inside the arrays. One with an associative key, and one with a Numeric Key, for each field.

Comment: Check my update. I'm now forcing`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` in `PDO::fectch()`. This should fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

It is already an associative array, containing several distinct records.

Use `foreach` to get each record separately:

```
foreach($rows as $id => $row)
{
    echo "Record n°" . $id . ": " . $row['user_id'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I can't do that, because the script i'm doing already has a foreach. Inside this foreach, i have one variable, that's the user id, and it swap between two values. That's why i need to have the array as i said, so i can get different data based on the user_id.